# Dealing with duplicate and cross-tenant accounts in a multi-tenancy environment

Tags: design-patterns, multi-tenant

Is there a good "vetted" way to handle having multiple copies of the same account for different tenants? Are there some recommended design patterns?

In my situation, our application routes tenant based on the URL:

```
https://ten_a.software.com  --> selects "ten_a" tenant
https://ten_b.software.com  --> selects "ten_b" tenant
```

I am running into this problems:

Bob, who has account at `ten_a`, tries to login to `ten_b.software.com`, or even `softare.com`. If Bob is simply typing URLs in his browser, it is not much to let him know to use the correct address, but this gets more complicated when another entity is trying to authenticate Bob through, say, OAuth2 exchange. That third party may not know which tenant to direct its auth request. I only see two solutions here:

1. Ask Bob to enter his tenant information alongside his username/password. Big minus is user experience and UI overhead.
2. Implement a tenant router based on usernames. Big minus here is this seems like a minefield.  It gets further complicated when Bob has an account on two different tenants.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Does Bob have a global account, or does he have one account for each tenancy?

Comment: @aaaantoine one for each tenancy. There are no global tenants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm twisting your question a bit here.  Suppose Bob has accounts on both `ten_a` and `ten_b`?

If Bob were to be given a network-wide account that could link Bob's tenant-specific accounts together under one user, that would simplify support for 3rd party authentication.  In an ambiguous situation, there will still be UI overhead because Bob will then have to select the correct tenant, but that's a necessary evil.

If the problem is that Bob@ten_a is a different person than Bob@ten_b, then URL routing becomes critical, especially in light of OAuth support.  Only enable OAuth when Bob visits a specific tenancy (e.g. `ten_a.software.com`).  Attempting to log into `software.com` using OAuth should fail.

If Bob forgets the tenant-specific URL, it should be the tenant administrator's responsibility to remind him.

This is roughly the pattern that [Google Apps](https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/) was still using when I had an account there years ago.

Comment: Thanks. That's a pretty comprehensive stab at the problem, and given that ti's the only one, it deserves an accept :)